# How do I describe an unstable network of connected pieces?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or idiom which describes an **unstable, may-break-at-any-time collection of related/connected items**.

For example,

> That framework's really fragile; it's just a _____.

or

> Be careful what you change, or else the _____ will fall apart.

I'm looking to use this is a software development context, but something tech-agnostic would be great. I'm trying to describe the gigantic tree of dependencies and hacks that make up many cross-platform mobile development frameworks (Cordova, Ionic, etc.) and their respective plugins.

Comment: Being a Software Engineer myself,  I am all too familiar with the point you're trying to convey. And while I would be more than happy to provide you with a list of phrases we have for "That framework's really fragile; it's just a _____ ..." I don't think any would be appropriate for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: https://techcrunch.com/2014/03/29/the-internet-is-held-together-with-bubble-gum-and-baling-wire/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like a ***[house of cards](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/house-of-cards)*** to me:

> a complicated organization or plan that is very weak and can easily be destroyed or easily go wrong
>   <sub>*from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/house-of-cards)*</sub>